# Table disappears after switching between Markdown and Rendered output views

Tags: bug, diff, tables

The rendered markdown table disappears after switching back and forth between Markdown view and Rendered output view.

I can reproduce it with Firefox 84.0.1 and disabled uBlock Origin on [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27994262).

[image: gif of bug]

Comment: Yep, it's a JS problem. https://dev.stackoverflow.com/content//Js/review.en.js It unconditionally calls `$diffs.find('table:visible').hide();` for some reason.

Comment: Already reported here: [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357464/289905).

Comment: Also repro'd in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in the meantime:

[image: GIF of working switch between side-by-side and side-by-side-markdown]